# Selecting decimal and string anonymous types in single LINQ query that's grouped

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to work this bit of LINQ I'm working with in my code. The end goal is to output the sums (which is working fine) as well as the names for people those sums were done in relation to.

For instance, if Adam and Brad do a deal, it should output something like:

`Adam and Brad made $50 / £20 profit`

All of this information is stored across multiple tables within the DB, and grouped by the partnership id. It looks like this:

```
var Profit = (from Yield in Total
              join w in totalsDB.wager on Yield.wager_id equals w.id
              join p in totalsDB.partnership on w.partnership_id equals p.id
              join e1 in totalsDB.employees on p.employee1_id equals e1.id
              join e2 in totalsDB.employees on p.employee2_id equals e2.id
              group Yield by p.partnership_id into set
              select new
              {
                Partnership = set.Key,
                USD = set.Sum(s => (decimal)s.p_and_l / (decimal)s.exchange_usd),
                GBP = set.Sum(s => (decimal)s.p_and_l / (decimal)s.exchange_gbp),
                size = set.Sum(s => (decimal)s.size / (decimal)s.exchange_gbp),
                Employee1 = set.Select(s => s.e1.name),
                Employee2 = set.Select(s => s.e2.name)
               }).ToList();
```

I have a feeling that the issue may either be with the way I'm joining the employee table twice, or possibly with the way that I'm trying to select it.

I'm then trying to output in the following ways (have tried both and although they 'mostly' work...the employee names is kicking me in the teeth:

```
foreach (var partnerYield in Profit)
                    {
                     string[] partYield = new string[] { "{0} and {1} made ${2:#,0} / £{3:#,0} profit", partnerYield.Employee1.ToString(), partnerYield.Employee2.ToString(), partnerYield.USD.ToString(), partnerYield.GBP.ToString() };
                     listview_partnerYield.Items.Add(partnerYield.Partnership.ToString()).SubItems.AddRange(partYield);

// OR

                     txt_partnerYield.Text += string.Format("{0} and {1} made ${1:#,0} / £{2:#,0} profit" + System.Environment.NewLine, partnerYield.Employee1, partnerYield.Employee2, partnerYield.USD, partnerYield.GBP);
                    }
```

As it stands, it's either not working at all returning nulls for employee ids, or outputting system.anonymous type in the text/list field.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each partnership has two employees, you can pick them with the `First` method with returns `Employee`, rather than using `Select`, which returns `IEnumerable<Employee>`

```
Employee1 = set.First(s => s.e1.name),
Employee2 = set.First(s => s.e2.name)
```

This assumes that all partnerships have matching employees. If some employees could be missing, replace `First` with `FirstOrDefault`.